# the right way of using glob to query files

Tags: python-3.x, glob

There are 99999 files in a folder, I can query these files as follows

```
data_dir = Path('D:\data\openimage-2020')
dfile_list =sorted(data_dir.glob('test\*.jpg'))
len(dfile_list)
```

It gives right answer as 99999

However, when I use the code as follows

```
dfile_list_1 = sorted(glob.glob('D:\data\openimage-2020\test\*.jpg'))
len(dfile_list_1)
```

It gives 0 instead. Why the second way of using glob does not work?

Comment: `\t` in a string is the tab character. Use forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Comment: It's not well known, but API calls (INT 21h, in those days) have handled `/` in path names since DOS 2.0, when paths were first implemented. Windows and NT API calls have always allowed them.